# How to add the invoice origin field to a qweb report?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I want to add source document 'origin' field  from "account.invoice" model to qweb report and I dont know the syntax
I only need the syntax to add this field all other code I wrote it
Thanks in advance.

```
class make_fields (models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    gt_origin = fields.Many2one('account.invoice')
```

---

```
<t t-foreach="o.gt_origin" t-as="line">
    `enter code here`<span t-field="line.gt_origin.origin"/>
 </t>
```

Comment: no thing appear in the report after I wrote this code

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to make a foreach loop. This should be enough:

```xml
<t t-if="o.gt_origin">
    <span t-field="o.gt_origin.origin" />
</t>
```